# SSIS returning all the values in a column as null while running the job through SQL Server

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssis, bids

I have a SSIS Package which works fine when I execute it through the SQL Server Business Intelligence Studio. However, when the job is run as it is scheduled to do so or when I manually start the job through SQL Server, there is this one field where all its values comes back as null. All other fields come back fine. What could be causing this problem?

Answer (score 0):

At first check in the database that the specific field has values rather than NULL.

Then, you can check the mapping of that field. I think the field is not mapped(or ignored) to the corresponding field.

Comment: When I check the database the field does have the values as null when this job is run through the database. The field is also mapped properly. When I run the package through BIDS I do get the correct results with the fields not being null. It's only one field that comes out this way. I don't understand...